# Complex SQL or Eloquent query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have this Database schema

[exercise_quiz table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRr0l.png)

```
CREATE TABLE `exercise_quiz` (
  `exercise_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `quiz_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `answer` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`exercise_id`,`quiz_id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `exercise_quiz_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  KEY `exercise_quiz_quiz_id_foreign` (`quiz_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `exercise_quiz_exercise_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`exercise_id`) REFERENCES `exercises` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `exercise_quiz_quiz_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`quiz_id`) REFERENCES `quizzes` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `exercise_quiz_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

[exercises table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfHdd.png)

```
CREATE TABLE `exercises` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `course_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `exercises_course_id_foreign` (`course_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `exercises_course_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`course_id`) REFERENCES `courses` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=145 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

[quizzes table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcuPZ.png)

```
CREATE TABLE `quizzes` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

[Example of data in exercise_quiz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgQDf.png)

How can I retrieve this, either with raw SQL or with Eloquent, in such a way as I’d have one single row for each exercise_id with one column with the average answer for each quiz_id ? something like

```
exercise_id ---  avg_quiz_1 ---- avg_quiz_2 ---- avg_quiz_3 ...
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  For queries questions, the best is to show how the table was defined (with types and options), provide a sample data set, provide the desired result, and what you have tried up to now.  You should not expect SO users to do all the work for you.

Comment: @Nic3500 I'm sorry, new here. I tried to be more extensive with the info provided. Thanks :)

Comment: Put the values in the question, not as images in the question.  So users will not click on external links (it's a trap!), others might not be able if on corporate networks, ...  It's also useful if the links go byebye to have complete questions.

Comment: @Nic3500 there!

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?